# HTML/CSS Un-ordered list Center Alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I am a first time HTML user and need help to center my current navigation bar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czpJr.jpg

The code for it is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>large background</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <!div class="navBar">

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about"><h2>ABOUT</h2></a></li>
                <li><a href="#home"><img src="ICON.jpg" width="60" height="60"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#music"><h2>MUSIC</h2></a></li>
            </ul>

        <!/div>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the relevant parts of the external stylesheet in this image(couldn't get it to work as a code block - noob me):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaIah.jpg

Please help me work out to make this navigation bar appear in the center of the page, and not on the left. I have tried changing the float left in the CSS but all is does is make the nav bar appear vertically not horizontally, and it still appears on the left :(

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: I think you need `.navBar {margin:0 auto;}`. But what does `<!div>` mean? And how come you managed to post the HTML  code, but not the CSS? Getting HTML to show up in here is more difficult than CSS.

Comment: Post your CSS code too.

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto;` on your `<div>`

Comment: .navBar {
    text-align:center;
}

Comment: Also, your attempt at polyglot markup fails, the fragment identifiers point nowhere, and I don't think `a {display:block}` is a good idea for unqualified `a` elements; you probably meant `.navBar a` as a selector.

Comment: @MrLister - sorry what do you mean by polyglot markup - I am very new to this haha

Comment: Polyglot markup is the official word for HTML files that can also be XHTML files. Now you have a slash at the end of the `link`, but slashes like that serve absolutely no purpose unless you're aiming for polyglot markup (so that your file can be parsed with an xml parser). But since you don't have a slash at the end of the `img`, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

to comment out HTML use this syntax (you're missing the dashes):

```
<div> this WILL show and be rendered </div>
<!--div> this WILL NOT show or be rendered </div-->
```

adding "float: left" to the li elements is forcing your elements to align to the left. To get the nav items to appear horizontally, use "display: inline-block;" instead. Also, you are using "align"... it shoudl be "text-align".

Example in codepen!

http://codepen.io/Drodarious/pen/bdmavb

Comment: Hey, that was great thanks. My nav bar is now aligned in the center, but the size of the image determines how far down (vertically) the nav bar sits on the page. Any way to fix this?

Comment: honestly, there is no simple way to do this. If you want to add icons to the nav, I would suggest using a font-icon pack life FontAwesome. Simple to use and lots of icons that look good.

Answer (score 0):

U can center your element like this(see example below: with the text align center on the ul).
u could also, provide a width to the ul, for example 300px , and then add margin:0 auto; margin auto won't work on a block element without setting its width. or you should use inline-block;

(http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/)

Ps  As h1 is a block element and a is an inline element the correct way is

```
    <h1><a href="#">This is a title</a></h1>
```

, when using the header.

Though because  is a block element it will take up all available space, meaning, all list items will still be underneath eachother, so specify the space it should take.

```css
header nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li { 
    display: inline; 
}

header nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>large background</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
                    <li><a href="#home"><img src="ICON.jpg" width="60" height="60"></a>
                    <li><a href="#music">MUSIC</a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

I suggest reading about: http://learnlayout.com/display.html

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: Hey guys, that was great thanks. My nav bar is now aligned in the center, but the size of the image determines how far down (vertically) the nav bar sits on the page. Any way to fix this?

Comment: You can give the li's a specific height , higher then the image , so all will have the same height. But i donno what u want to happen, what kind of behavior do u expect?